# Are two definitions of a topological limit point equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, limits

1) A point $x$ of a set $A$ is a limit point if [$x \in S$ $\&$ $S$ open] $\implies$ [$S \cap A \neq \emptyset$].

2) A sequence $x_{n} \to x$ if [$x \in S$ $\&$ $S$ open] $\implies$ [$x_{i} \in S$ for **all** i > N for some $N$]. A point $x$ of a set $A$ is a limit point if there is a sequence $x_{n} \to x$ for some $x_{n} \in A$.

Are these two definitions of a limit point $x$ of a set $A$ equivalent?

Comment: Are you taking sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ or $A/ \{x\}$.

Comment: Sequence {&x_{n}&} in A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no these two statements are not equivalent. Certainly we have that (2)$\Rightarrow$(1). That is to say that: If we have a nonconstant sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq A$ with $x_n\rightarrow x$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

However, (1) does not imply (2) in general. In a general topological space, sequences are inadequate. For equivalence, we need our space X to be second countable. Without this condition, (1) is not enough to build a sequence in A that converges to your limit point.

If you are interested, nets and filters remedy this problem. It is true in a general topological space $x$ is a limit point if and only if there is a nonconstant net $(x_\lambda)$ contained in $A$ that converges to x.